# Spring logging threshold not being set by logback

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j, logback

I am working with Spring (Core/Security/ldap and more), and logback.
But for some reason spring does not receive the loggin threshhold set in the logback XML
I can see that as well when i debug springs source code and i see that the

```
final boolean debug = logger.isDebugEnabled();
```

Is false

As well i would like to mention (I don't know if it has any relevance) that the logger that spring uses is:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
org.apache.commons.logging.Log
```

And not SLF4j like i use

So how am i supposed to enable the debug level and bring the logs into my SLF4J configuration..

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring by default uses Apache's Jakarta Commons Logging library. You need to disable it and instead use the slf4j bridge. You should have the following (among others)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then your `logback.xml` or other configuration can set the log level. For example,

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add following dependency into your pom.xml file :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and Add following lines into your logback.xml file :

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"
    level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.core" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.context" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.ui" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.web.context" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.aop" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="OFF" />
<logger name="org.springframework.jndi" level="OFF" />
```

You can set level according to your requirement or If you want to OFF all log level of spring then just add one line :

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `commons-logging.jar` by `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`. The [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging) explains this in detail.

Comment: can you please explain?